# Systematic way of finding shortcut associations

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity and all that.
Is there a way to systematically lookup for any shortcuts associated with a key combination?
I could scan the System Settings gui and Compiz Setting manager for the binding but it is far from being efficient, plus I never know if I am missing a possible source of bindings.

Specifically I am looking for any bindings for <kbd>alt+up</kbd> and <kbd>alt+down</kbd> but I would like to know if there is a general method.

Comment: Are you looking for system key bindings or *any* binding, including those of individual applications?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I am looking for key bindings which are active at a global level, say at the wm level. These include the system settings ones but also the ones set for every compiz plugin.

Comment: I see. Actually I now notice that what I wanted to suggest has already been added as an answer. :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you could do something like

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep keybindings | grep '\[.\+\]'
```

from the command line to, extract all the non-empty `keybindings` from the dconf database.

Comment: thanks this is very close to what I wanted. However, there are many bindings which are not in the system settings, namely the ones set in Compiz manager. I am not referring to the ones of individual applications but just the global/wm-related ones.

Comment: I don't have access to a 14.04 installation with compiz right now, but for apps that save their settings in the local gconf database, you may be able to do something similar with the `gconftool` utility e.g. `gconftool -R /apps/compizconfig-1 | grep '<(Alt\|Control\|Shift)>'`

Answer (score 1):

Shortcuts:
`System settings` > `Keyboard` > `/Shortcuts\` - is one place to look.